# SQL LIMIT parametrizado no PHP com PDO

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

Há poucos dias, deixei de usar as funções `mysql_*`(por já serem obsoletas), e mudei para o `PDO`. Tenho uma função que faz *query* a base de dados, mas estou tendo alguns problemas no uso do `LIMIT` com *prepared statements*.

Eis o erro que obtenho:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message
>   'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an
>   error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''0', '4'' at
>   line 1' in /home/yuran/public_html/avec/DatabaseContent.php:30 Stack
>   trace: #0 /home/yuran/public_html/avec/DatabaseContent.php(30):
>   PDOStatement->execute(Array) #1
>   /home/yuran/public_html/avec/inc/header.php(43):
>   DatabaseContent->fetchSomeRows(Object(PDO), 'topics', 'topic_id',
>   'DSC', 0, 4) #2 /home/yuran/public_html/avec/index.php(7):
>   require_once('/home/yuran/pub...') #3 {main} thrown in
>   /home/yuran/public_html/avec/DatabaseContent.php on line 30

Este é o código da minha função.

```
<?php
private $sql = "SELECT * FROM ";
public function fetchSomeRows($conn, $table, $rowOrder, $direction, $initialLimit, $finalLimit)
{
    $this->sql .= "{$table} ORDER BY :roworder :direction LIMIT :initiallimit, :finallimit";
    $q = $conn->prepare($this->sql);
    $q->execute(array(':roworder' => $rowOrder,':direction'=>$direction,':initiallimit'=>$initialLimit,':finallimit'=>$finalLimit));
    $q->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    return $q;
}    
?>
```

Comment: Na verdade você poderia ter mudado para as funções `mysqli` que são quase idênticas e resolvia seu problema de forma mais simples e sem traumas.

Comment: Você deve informar outro trecho do código de onde venha a propriedade `$this->sql`. Pois a exceção informa um erro de sintaxe

Comment: @rray no caso de nomes de tabelas e' verdade que nao e' posivel efectuar o bind por isso que usei o {$table} mas nao sabia que o mesmo acontecia com o LIMIT.

Comment: Eu me enganei, até por isso removi o comentário, eu testei a resposta do @andré Ribeiro e funcinou, vivendo e aprendendo :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

O problema é que as variáveis de LIMIT e OFFSET estão sendo passadas como `PARAM_STR` e isso faz com que o PDO adicione apóstrofos nos números, gerando um erro de sintaxe.

Para resolver basta usar [`bindParam`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/pdostatement.bindparam.php) para especificar o tipo das variáveis que estão sendo passadas.

```
$q->bindParam(':finallimit', (int)$finalLimit, PDO::PARAM_INT); 
$q->bindParam(':initiallimit', (int)$initialLimit, PDO::PARAM_INT); 
$q->execute();
```

Nota: Os `(int)` ali são para garantir que as variáveis sejam passadas para função como `int`.

Comment: +1, não conhecia isso, raramente seto o tipo do dado.

Comment: Muito obrigado Andre, a solucao funcionou. Porem um outro problema surgiu com uum erro identico que nao sei como resolver. Por favor note que eu adaptei a sua solucao de acordo com o meu codigo, onde :roworder e :direction sao strings. Porem qundo tento executar ele da erro.

Comment: Eis aqui o erro :  [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/GCTQgrRK)

Comment: @Yuran Como os nomes de colunas e os parâmetros são do tipo string mas não podem estar entre apóstrofos/aspas, você não vai poder usar bindParam para isso. No seu caso você pode colocar essas variáveis diretamente na string da query. Ex.: `{$table} ORDER BY {$rowOrder} {$direction}`.