# Como funciona em PHP+PDO o parâmetro PDO::PARAM_STR

Tags: php, pdo

Exemplo:

```
$sth->bindValue(':calories', $calories, PDO::PARAM_INT);
```

`PDO::PARAM_INT`
Esse parâmetro é uma espécie de validação para tipo de dados ? Se for, porque não dá erro quando eu passo um inteiro?

Comment: Editei seu código. Peço que sempre que postar alguma pergunta você procure identar o código (deixe 1 linha em  branco após o texto, e após adicione 4 espaços antes do código "para que ele seja interpretado como código", ou apenas selecione o código e então clique no editor em `{ }`. 

Fora isso: você mencionou **PARAM_STR**, porém na sua questão estava **PARAM_INT**. Qual deles é o correto?

Comment: Não é uma validação. O PDO usa este parâmetro para identificar como montar a query corretamente. Por exemplo, strings devem estar entre aspas, já números não.

Comment: Ainda não vi um explicação oficial para isso, na prática é exatamente como o @Oeslei falou. Só via a diferença para usar a [clásula limit](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/51712/91)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assim como o [@Oeslei](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/11835/oeslei) disse, PDO::PARAM_INT (ou STR), não faz a validação do tipo do valor.

Para fazer isso no caso você deve usar o `filter_var`, por exemplo:

```
if (filter_var($suaVariavel, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT)) {
    // válido
} else {
    // inválido
}
```

### Links úteis

PHP Filter: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.filter.php

---

Qualquer dúvida, deixe um comentário abaixo.