# Qual a diferença de bindValue para um array executado diretamente no $pdo->execute()

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Atualmente eu uso uma programação como essa

```
<?php

$array = array('nome'=>'Alisson', 'idade'=>20);

$query = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO table (nome,idade) VALUES (:nome, :idade)");
$query->execute($array);

?>
```

Qual a diferença se eu usar o `bindValue` ao invez do `array()` ? Deixar meu código mais ou menos assim:

```
<?php

$query = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO table (nome,idade) VALUES (:nome, :idade)");

$query->bindValue(':nome', 'Alisson', PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->bindValue(':idade', '20', PDO::PARAM_STR);

$query->execute();

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como acréscimo à resposta do `@rray`, gostaria de destacar aqui a vantagem de utilização do `execute` com `array` em relação ao método `PDOStatment::bindValue`.

Muitas vezes os dados que queremos passar para o `bindValue` pode estar em um `array`. A utilização poderia ser trabalhosa se você fosse definir um por um.

Exemplo:

```
$array = array('nome'=>'Alisson', 'idade'=>20);

$query = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO table (nome,idade) VALUES (:nome, :idade)");

$query->bindValue(':nome', $array['nome'], PDO::PARAM_STR);

$query->bindValue(':idade', $array['idade'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

Quando eu precisei fazer uma operação de passar os valores de um `array` dinamicamente para o `bindValue`, a primeira coisa que eu pensei para diminuir o meu trabalho foi em fazer um `foreach`.

```
$array = array('nome'=>'Alisson', 'idade'=>20);

$query = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO table (nome,idade) VALUES (:nome, :idade)");

foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    $query->bindValue(":$key", $value, PDO::PARAM_STR);
}
```

No final das contas foi mais vantajoso usar `execute` passando o `array`.

## Pequena diferença

Por mais que não pareça, eu acabei notando uma pequena diferença entre os dois. Isso só é percepível quando usamos o caractere `?` para efetuar a 'vinculação de parâmetros'.

Veja:

```
$calories = 150;
$colour = 'red';
$sth = $dbh->prepare('SELECT name, colour, calories
    FROM fruit
    WHERE calories < ? AND colour = ?');
$sth->bindValue(1, $calories, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$sth->bindValue(2, $colour, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sth->execute();
```

Observe que é necessário definir a posição das interrogações (`?`) para poder definir qual valor será vinculado a tal parâmetro.

Porém no caso do `execute` é um pouco diferente. O vínculo dos parâmetros ocorrerá de acordo com a posição do elemento no `array`

```
$calories = 150;
$colour = 'red';
$sth = $dbh->prepare('SELECT name, colour, calories
    FROM fruit
    WHERE calories < ? AND colour = ?');
$sth->execute(array($calories, $colour));
```

A contagem nesse caso ocorre a partir do `0`. Se você tentar nomear erroneamente um `array` (numericamente), ocorrerá um erro ao tentar rodar o método `execute`:

```
$calories = 150;
$colour = 'red';
$sth = $dbh->prepare('SELECT name, colour, calories
    FROM fruit
    WHERE calories < ? AND colour = ?');
$sth->execute(array(1 => $calories, 2 => $colour));
```

> PHP warning:  PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined

Answer (score 3):

A diferença entre passar os valores com  `bindValue()` e `execute()` do primeiro com o segundo código é **nenhuma**.

Ambos os parâmentros estão sendo enviados como string, todos os argumentos enviados em `execute()` são do tipo string enquanto `bindValue()` permite outros tipos como o `PDO::PARAM_INT` que é usado praticamente em um clásula `LIMIT/OFFSET`

**Relacionado:**

[Qual a diferença entre bindParam e bindValue?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/87384/91)

[SQL LIMIT parametrizado no PHP com PDO](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/51712/91)