# PHP PDO, qual a diferença prática no envio de parâmetro?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Estou com uma dúvida utilizando o `pdo` no `php`, existe alguma diferença prática na execução utilizando essas duas abordagens?

```
$db = new PDO("ok");
$sql = "INSERT INTO tabela (campo1, campo2) VALUES (:campo1, :campo2)";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindParam(':campo1', "campo1", PDO::PARAM_STR);       
$stmt->bindParam(':campo2', "campo2", PDO::PARAM_STR); 
$stmt->execute();

$sql = "INSERT INTO tabela (campo1, campo2) VALUES (?, ?)"
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
$stmt ->execute(array("campo1","campo2");
```

Sempre vi tutoriais e exemplos utilizando ambas abordagens, mas nunca soube direito qual era a diferença....

E ainda existe a passagem de parâmetro usando o `bindValue`.
Existe alguma delas que é mais segura? No que influência? Desempenho? Ou existe alguma mais recomendada?

Comment: [Qual a diferença de bindValue para um array executado diretamente no $pdo->execute](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/104628/91)

Comment: Certo, mas existe diferença entre usar `?` ou `:` ?

Comment: Não, pode usar qualquer um desde que não misture eles.

Comment: Sim, apesar da resposta ainda me deixar meio inconformado rs, não existe nenhuma diferença prática, mas a bordagem é bem diferente, então pra que existe?

Comment: Pq não é prático ter dezenas de chamada de `bindValue/Param()` passar um array para `execute()` é mais simples mas veja que existe um caso onde isso não funciona.

Comment: E qual seria? Pode dar um exemplo?

Comment: Esse caso => [SQL LIMIT parametrizado no PHP com PDO](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/51712/91)